# General purpose compute with Vertex/Pixel shaders (Open GL / DirectX)

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, directx, shader, gpgpu

I have a question regarding compute shaders. are compute shaders available in DX 9? would it be still possible to use a compute shader with a DX9 driver if there is no compute shader fragment on the GPU? ( SGX 545 does not have it, but SGX 6X generation is going to have it), as far as what IMG says. I would like to know If i can do some simple general purpose programming on SGXs GPUs with DirectX9 or OpenGL drivers.

Also, is there anyway I can use OpenGL vertex shaders for GPGPU programming? Here is what I am thinking: 
  I will load my Matrices/ data into the vertex buffer, and bind them to the program context. I will load some other static variables into the uniform variables, and my actual compute program into vertex shader. It looks feisible till this point ( does it? )  but the output from the vertex shader will go through rasterization and will be fed to fragment shader ( according to how things go in openGL). Is there anyway I can prevent the data to be going through whole of the graphics pipleline, or can I intercept after vertex shader is done with executing, and somehow read the values and time taken for execution?

Answer (score 4):

> is there anyway I can use OpenGL vertex shaders for GPGPU programming?

The stuff that goes out of the vertex shader is generally interpolated at the raserization stage. In old versions of openGL you could specify if such interpolation should or should not happen for specific variables. I don't know if you can still do that... Yes you still can (thx to datenwolf for the tip)...  but a better approach, in my opinion, is to use fragment shaders. Render to a full frame, using a simple vertex shader that renders two triangles that cover the whole frame (a quad), as for any post process effect, and do your computation in the fragment shader. Put the data you want to use as input in textures, and render your results to other textures using frame buffer objects (FBO).

Comment: I am quite fond of this approach myself, because it allows for a lot of GPGPU stuff in really unexpected contexts (i.e. _WebGL_). If you can structure your algorithm to work well in implementations that do not support floating-point render targets you would be surprised how many devices are capable of GPGPU. Since transform feedback is not possible in OpenGL ES 2.0, I think the only way to portably tackle this is to use the vertex shader stage as a simple passthrough like you said and do the work in a fragment shader.

Comment: Well, there's one drawback by using the fragment state for computations: It doesn't allow you to perform scatter writes, which can be a problem for some algorithms. Depending on what you actually want to do, you could use the vertex shader stage to perform "scattering" computations, emitting the location of single pixel points and have the fragment shader perform localized compuations.

Comment: @darius: It's still possible to turn of interpolation for selected varyings.

Comment: @datenwolf Using the vertex shader for the scattering writes is an amazing good solution. That's really going to be useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: @darius  Thank you so much. is there any tutorial, or sample programs kind of stuff available that would help me to start with? I am a beginner in OpenGL.

Comment: @user2755509 http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch29.html but if you are a beginner I'd advise you to learn first to use glsl for graphics (even if just as an exercise), to get some decent understanding of the tools you are going to use. A good starting point is to read these tutorials http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/ and then focus on some post processing technique, or if you have enough time, on deferred shading. Here's  a good tutorial for that http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anyway I can prevent the data to be going through whole of
>   the graphics pipleline, or can I intercept after vertex shader is done
>   with executing, and somehow read the values and time taken for
>   execution?

Yes.
Potentially you could use the vertex shader for your computations, turn off the tessellations stages and geometry shader and intercept the results from the transform feedback.

Below is the [OpenGL Rendering Pipeline](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview).

The optional stages have a striped border.
The programmable stages are blue.

[image: OpenGL Rendering Pipeline]

Comment: In fact, you can probably short-cut rasterization simply by setting the W coordinate of every vertex to 0.0. In theory the perspective divide would cause every one of those vertices to be clipped. Of course if you wanted to use W for something meaningful you're out of luck :) And this does not solve the OpenGL ES dilemma unfortunately, as ES and ES 2.0 do not have transform feedback.

Comment: @DylanHolmes : Thank you so much. so you mean to say I can turn off the pixel shader aswell? is there any way to read data from transform feed back? Is there any tutorial, or sample programs kind of stuff available that would help me to start with? I am a beginner in OpenGL.

Comment: You can "turn off" the pixel shader by setting the w coordinate of every vertex to 0, like @AndonM.Coleman said above. An excellent tutorial to start with would be http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/