# Using OpenGL on Android NDK for making computation and without display results

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I would like to use OpenGL for data processing. The results of the processing shall not be displayed, I only need to do some computation like matrix multiplication and texturization.

Is it possible to use OpenGL shader program without a display? Might I ask for a code snippet?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665680/general-purpose-compute-with-vertex-pixel-shaders-open-gl-directx, also if you are focused on Android may want to look into RenderScript.

Comment: You have a lot of reading ahead. Yes, you can do it. Just use an off-screen framebuffer and read the results. The shaders don't need to be changed at all. Check any OpenGL ES book on how to do that. I would too take a look at RenderScript if it is just for computing.